# Using Sockets in Xcode Cpp

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode11

I am making a socket program in a MacOS environment using Xcode 11.3.1. I am currently making project my project with template `Project - MacOs - Command Line Tool` with language C++. However, I am facing some issues when I am accepting my Socket.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define PORT 37716

class Communications{
public:
    int server_fd, new_socket, valread;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int opt = 1;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    char buffer[1024] = {0};

Communications(){
    server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt));

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT );

    bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address));
    listen(server_fd, 3);
    cout << "[Server] Listening in port " << PORT << endl;

    new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen);
    cout << "[Server] Client has successfully connected." << endl;
    }
};

int main(void){
    Communications CommunicationsObj = Communications();
    return 0;
}
```

This is my main class for my code. It's just a basic port binding, listening and accepting sequence. I have confirmed that this code is working when it is compiled by G++ on terminal. I have tested with my simple Python code. However, when I am debugging with my Xcode (That Play button on the left top), I cannot connect to this program using socket. It seems that Xcode is blocking network connections when running this code.

For your information, the Python script that I used to connect to my C++ program was something like this.

```
from socket import *
port = 37716
ClientSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
ClientSock.connect(('', port))
```

I am currently testing on a same machine with internal network, meaning that all connections would go to 127.0.0.1

When I have compiled with G++ and ran in a terminal environment, everything goes well. However when debugging on Xcode, these error appear.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "a.py", line 7, in <module>
client_sock.connect(('',port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

In the C++ side of the program, the screen is like

```
[Server] Listening in port 37716
```

this forever. Meaning that Xcode did not receive any transmission on that port.

I have currently looked for many ways throughout the internet including Stack Overflow. I have tried adding "Capabilities" in Xcode settings and enabled network server and client. That did not help and resulted another problem with Xcode. I have tried other methods such as debugging Xcode with root permissions but that did not work. Also, For your information, my port 37716 is an empty port and no process is using it right now.

Comment: Check the return codes from `bind` and `listen` for success. Either (or both) could have failed and you'll never know.

Comment: @user4581301 both bind and listen function returns 0 as their return values. Just checked few seconds ago.

Comment: Groovy. That's the low hanging fruit gone. My Mac-fu is pretty much non existent. Do you have [a `netstat`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat) or netstat-like program you can call? On a regular Unix box, I'd run `netstat -lpt` and make sure the OS agreed that the port was being listened on.

Comment: In both cases `netstat -lpt` returns `unknown or uninstrumented protocol`. However when I am doing `lsof -nP -iTCP:37716 | grep LISTEN`, running binary through terminal does show it's process. However, when using the same command in Xcode, it does not show the process. I guess it is due to the Xcode IDE itself, rather than the code or socket.

Comment: Outside of my skill set then. Hopefully someone who does know the ins and outs of XCode can help you. If you figure it out first, please self answer. This one is gonna be interesting, methinks.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks. I will just keep trying until I reach the solution.

Comment: @user4581301 Just let you know. I found out why this happened. It seems that not including a library and wrong sequence of loading header file made this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same problem, and I just SOLVED it!

For some crazy reason, when you put:

```
using namespace std;
```

the socket connection does not work on MacOS. You need to manually put `std::` before every method/class that need it.

[For example: `std::cout`, `std::endl` and `std::string`]

Answer (score 0):

I tried like more than 100 methods in last 5 hours just on this one. And found that it worked in this way. There were some problems with this code.

First problem was that I did not include `#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>` this header file. 
The second problem was due to wrong sequence of including header files or library.
I was using another .framework library called CUESDK.framework. If I load that library earlier than loading this code, it crashes. It is kind of odd why it happens.

I am not 100% sure about whether it is solved or not. But I will just post my code below if it can help anyone!

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <iostream>

#define PORT 37716
#include <stdio.h>

class ConnectrionBridge{
public:
    int servsock;
    int enable;
    int port;

ConnectrionBridge(void){
        servsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if(servsock < 0) perror("Failed to create a socket");

        enable = 1;
        setsockopt(servsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&enable, sizeof(int));

        //Bind to "any" address with a specific port to listen on that port
        sockaddr_in serv_addr;
        memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

        bind(servsock, (sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

        listen(servsock, 5);
        std::cout<< "Listening Server on port " << PORT << std::endl;


        //Accept a client
        struct sockaddr_storage client_addr_info;
        socklen_t len = sizeof client_addr_info;


        int clientsock = accept(servsock, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr_info, &len);

        std::cout << "connected" << std::endl;
}
};
```

Comment: You deleted  the line "using namespace std;", was this that did the trick actually. Try using it again and you will see that the problem will happen again

Comment: @BrenoMedeirosdeOliveira Oh, Did not know that solved the problem. I thought #include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h> solved the problem. I will accept your answer as the answer for this question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

•When you include `iostream`, `cout` in the namespace called `std`. You have to put `std::` before `cout` or use, `using` statement to bring to it to the current scope.

### •You should use

```
while (true)
{
if ((new_socket=accept(server_fd,(struct sockaddr *)&address,(socklen_t*)addrlen))>=0){break;}
}
```

for accepting a connection.

•Replace `INADDR_ANY` with `htonl(INADDR_ANY)`